# Why did Dumbledore ask McGonagall to bring Fang before questioning Crouch?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, Dumbledore asked Professor McGonagall to bring Hagrid's dog Fang to his office before questioning Crouch Jr. Why did he do this?

> "Minerva, kindly go down to Hagrid's house, where you will find a large black dog sitting in the pumpkin patch. Take the dog up to my office, tell him I will be with him shortly, then come back here."
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, Chapter 35 "Veritaserum"

Comment: The quote didn't mention the dog in question was Fang - and it wasn't.

Comment: In any Question like that, could you first explain your own ideas? "Why did…?" is one thing. Wouldn't "I think the reason X did Y was…" and I'm looking for either justification or a better explanation…" would be more interesting?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The black dog was Sirius in his animagus form. The following chapter (GoF chapter 36) hopefully makes this clearer:

> ‘I want you to come up to my office first, Harry,’ he said quietly , as they headed up the passageway. ‘Sirius is waiting for us there.’

Comment: Wow, an answer to a question I didn't know I had. What a wonderful post; question and answer. :)

Comment: To supplement this answer, McGonagall certainly knew who Fang was, and Dumbledore would have referred to the dog by name. It's 99% certain that she also knew that the large black dog was Sirius in Animagus form, but Dumbledore said it this way to provide her with plausible deniability. (Not that McGonagall would likely need it, and her sense of honor would drive her to eschew it in most cases, but Dumbledore looks out after his own.)

Comment: The other clue was in the *"tell him I will be with him shortly"* line.  Why would you bother telling that to a dog?  Unless you knew it wasn't really a dog...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman To be fair, I've found it perfectly normal for people to talk to dogs without any expectation that the dog will understand them.

Comment: @Abless: You would be surprised what dogs can understand.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman even if it were an actual dog, Dumbledore is known to have said weirder stuff.

Comment: @EvilSnack Actually, the only people who really knew (not just suspected) that the big black dog was Sirius, were Dumbledore, Harry, Ron, Hermione, the members of the Order of the Pheonix, and Peter Wormtail (and because of him probably Lord Voldemort, too), unless I forgot someone. It is highly unlikely that Dumbledor would tell McGonagall, and it even says in the part where she is told to get Sirius, that Dumbledore ignored [Mcgonagall's] confused expression at those odd orders (go get a big black dog from a giant's pupkin patch and tell it to wait in my office while I interrogate this guy).

Comment: @CaptainKirk McGonagall was of the Order, so if the others knew, she would know, too; although we know from later in the third book that at least one Order member (Molly) did not know that Sirius was not a Death Eater.